# Java 8: check for common elements in two lists using streams

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, java-stream

I'm looking for a statment to check if there is any match in two lists of Users, according to Username.

```
List<User> a;
List<User> b;
for (User user : a) {
    for (User newUser : b) {
        if (user.getName().equals(newUser.getName())) {
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write this in java 8? Somthing like this:

```
List<User> intersect = a.stream()
                    .filter(User::getName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: [how to avoid npe using java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964811/java-8-check-for-common-elements-in-two-lists-using-streams)

Answer (score 3):

When User is correctly defined with a `hashCode` and `equals` (otherwise you might try `TreeSet` instead of `HashSet`), do set-operations:

```
Set<User> common = new HashSet<>(a);
common.retainAll(b);
```

If `User.getName` is not used for equality:

```
Set<User> common = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(User::getName));
common.addAll(a);
common.retainAll(b);
```

Two nested for loops on lists (also as streams) would have complexity O(N²),
whereas this is O(N.log N).

Comment: `retainAll` returns `boolean`

Comment: Would this automatically call getName?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Khazraji you hit the weak spot; thanks. Added a comparator. If two different users can have the same name, it would make more sense to return a `Set<String>` of names. Then a Stream solution with a mapping would be in order.

Comment: @AhmadAl-Khazraji `new TreeSet<>(a, Comparator.comparing(User::getName))` should keep only users with no duplicate names.

Comment: @JoopEggen there is no such a constructor in Java 8.
Should I import a certin library?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Khazraji my error, one needs 2 calls. Corrected, Sorry, today I should not have played on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below:

```
List<User> intersect = a.stream()
                     .filter(b::contains)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You need to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `User`. 
For optimization, you can convert `b` to `HashSet` first.

Comment: I can't overreide any method in the class User!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that using `Stream.anyMatch`(this would `break` within `if`) could be :

```
a.stream().filter(user -> b.stream().anyMatch(newUser -> user.getName().equals(newUser.getName())))
          .map(User::getName)
          .forEach(System.out::println); // logic inside 'if' here (print for e.g.)
```

If you want to repeat the loop(`if` logic) for all such matches :

```
a.forEach(user -> b.stream()
                   .filter(newUser -> user.getName().equals(newUser.getName()))
                   .map(newUser -> user.getName())
                   .forEach(System.out::println));
```

Comment: You can save one `user.getName()` call per user, by simply doing the `map(User::getName)` *first*.