# Finding similar but not equal entities across two lists (Java)

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Let's say I have a class 'Person' like this:

```java
public class Person {
   String name;
   int age;
   String address;
   // Getters and Setters etc.
}
```

And I have two lists of 'Person': a list to create and a list to delete.

Delete List =

```
[
   {
       "name: "David"
       "age": 30,
       "address": "10 Main St."
   },
   {
       "name: "Mary"
       "age": 31,
       "address": "8 Main St."
   },
   {
       "name: "John"
       "age": 40,
       "address": "9 Side St."
   }
]
```

Create List =

```
[
   {
       "name: "David"
       "age": 30,
       "address": "50 Fleet St."
   },
   {
       "name: "Oliver"
       "age": 31,
       "address": "40 10th St."
   },
   {
       "name: "Jane"
       "age": 40,
       "address": "1 Broadway"
   }
]
```

I want to get a pair (or list of pairs) where the name and age are the same in the LHS and RHS but the address is different. The idea is that I have a list of entities to delete and list of entities to create, but in the case of `David`, I don't want to delete the entity and create a new one, because there are dependencies on it. I just want to change his address.

There are no unique identifiers in `Person` so I cannot just do a comparison by id.

Comment: *Has* David just changed address? Or *are* there two Davids? How do *you* differentiate?

Comment: You can't know they are the same if you don't have a unique identifier for each person (like ID) - This is true while assuming the lists you get are in JSON format and not already loaded each into a ```person``` class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8: check for common elements in two lists using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964811/java-8-check-for-common-elements-in-two-lists-using-streams). The top voted answer's second approach uses a comparator, which is what you would want to use - using name and age.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I want to get a pair (or list of pairs) where the name and age are the same in the LHS and RHS but the address is different. The idea is that I have a list of entities to delete and list of entities to create, but in the case of `David`, I don't want to delete the entity and create a new one, because there are dependencies on it. I just want to change his address.

Comment: @ShimonCohen That's the issue though, I don't have identifiers for this class. Also, ignore that the lists are represented in json in my question. I just thought that would be the easiest way to represent the data. I am only dealing with Java objects here.

Comment: @DaithiG the information in your last two comments should have been in your initial question. Please [edit] your question to include this information so others will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

In the real world, you don't have enough information to decide if a record is a different person or just an address change.

If you are playing in a toy environment where you will never encounter two people with the same name and age, then THAT (name & age) is your composite primary key and you can write a `hashCode()` and `equals()` based on that.  In which case this is a dup of [Java 8: check for common elements in two lists using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964811/java-8-check-for-common-elements-in-two-lists-using-streams)